# set style background-image in the component using a variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm passing a variable customPhoto into the component and want to use it inside the const bg to use in the style. The example below doesn't work - what should I change?

```
let bg = {
            backgroundImage: {`url(${customPhoto})`}
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

The only change I could see in your code is that remove curly brackets before url and at the end

Change

```
   backgroundImage: {`url(${customPhoto})`}
```

To

```
   backgroundImage: `url(${customPhoto})`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do inline-css
`` <div style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${customPhoto})` }}> ``

Comment: Inline css is good for experiments but they are not recommended in real time

Comment: Thanks @HemadriDasari I didn't know. And by real time I assume you mean production environment?

Comment: Yes it’s not recommended to use inline css